# qtpropertyanimation only change the scale

Tags: python, pyqt5

I used animator class to generate ellipseobject and also add animation to them, the goal is only change the scale (from double size to normal size) of the dot, but not do the translate. Right now what I am facing is the dot does shrink, but it moves from the location where (x y value are double with its original x y value) to its original x y location.

Here is the animator class

```
class Animator:
    def __init__(self, animation_config, num_rows, num_cols, background_colour, parent, user_idx = 0, resolution_width = 1920,
                  resolution_height = 1200, log_file_path = "coordinates.txt"):
        with open(log_file_path, "w") as log_file:
            log_file.write("")

        circle = animation_config["circle"]
        self.__cur_circle = None
        self.__cur_colour = None
        self.__animated_colour = QColor(*circle["colour"])
        self.__log_file_path = log_file_path

        # Initialize the circle table

        diamond_square = DiamondSquare()
        self.__user_idx = user_idx % 64
        shift_xn = diamond_square.dx[user_idx]
        shift_yn = diamond_square.dy[user_idx]
        intv_x = (resolution_width - 20) / 10
        intv_y = (resolution_height - 20) / 10
        print(shift_xn,shift_yn)
        self.__circle_table = []
        y = 0
        for i in range (11):
            circles = []
            x = 0
            for j in range (11):
                cir_x = (j * intv_x) + shift_xn
                cir_y = (i * intv_y) + shift_yn
                print(cir_x,cir_y)
                if cir_x <= resolution_width and cir_y <= resolution_height:
                    circles.append(EllipseObject(parent,cir_x,cir_y, x, y, intv_x, intv_y,
                                                 hidden_colour = background_colour,
                                                 display_colour=self.__animated_colour))
                    x += 1
            y += 1

            self.__circle_table.append(circles)

        # Initalize the first animation
        self.__first = QPropertyAnimation()
        self.__first.setPropertyName(b"scale")
        self.__first.setDuration(animation_config["animation_duration"])
        self.__first.setStartValue(2)
        self.__first.setEndValue(1)
```

and here is my EllipseObject class

```
class EllipseObject(QGraphicsWidget):
    def __init__(
        self,
        parent,
        x = 0,
        y = 0,
        ind_x = 0,
        ind_y = 0,
        intv_x = 0,
        intv_y = 0,
        width = 20,
        height = 20,
        hidden = True,
        hidden_colour = QColor(Qt.white),
        display_colour = QColor(Qt.black)
        ):

        super().__init__(parent)
        self.__x = x
        self.__y = y
        self.__ind_x = ind_x
        self.__ind_y = ind_y
        self.__intv_x = intv_x
        self.__intv_y = intv_y
        self.__height = height
        self.__width = width
        self.hidden = hidden
        self.hidden_colour = hidden_colour
        self.display_colour = display_colour

    def paint(self, painter, option, widget = None):
        colour = QColor(Qt.white) if self.hidden else self.display_colour
        painter.setRenderHint(QPainter.Antialiasing)
        painter.setPen(colour)
        painter.setBrush(QBrush(colour))
        # painter.drawEllipse(self.__x, self.__y, self.__width, self.__height)
        painter.drawEllipse(self.boundingRect())
        # point = self.mapToScene(self.boundingRect().center())
        # print("Draw this ",point.x(), point.y())

    def get_coordinates(self):
        point = self.mapToScene(self.boundingRect().center())
        return (point.x(), point.y())

    def boundingRect(self):
        return QRectF(self.__x,
                      self.__y,
                      self.__height, self.__width)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are probably observing is that it is rising with respect to the upper left corner and will give you the appearance that it is moving. The `QGraphicsItem` has a property called `transformOriginPoint` with respect to which transformations, such as rotation and scaling, are performed and which is found at point (0, 0). In your case your code has several errors, you must set the position with `setPos()` and not through `boundingRect()`, so that the scaling is with respect to the center of the item establishes that the `boundingRect()` is symmetric.

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *

class EllipseObject(QGraphicsWidget):
    def __init__(
        self,
        parent=None,
        x = 0,
        y = 0,
        ind_x = 0,
        ind_y = 0,
        intv_x = 0,
        intv_y = 0,
        width = 20,
        height = 20,
        hidden = True,
        hidden_colour = QColor(Qt.white),
        display_colour = QColor(Qt.black)
        ):

        super().__init__(parent)
        self.__x = x
        self.__y = y
        self.__ind_x = ind_x
        self.__ind_y = ind_y
        self.__intv_x = intv_x
        self.__intv_y = intv_y
        self.__height = height
        self.__width = width
        self.hidden = hidden
        self.hidden_colour = hidden_colour
        self.display_colour = display_colour
        self.setPos(self.__x, self.__y)

    def paint(self, painter, option, widget = None):
        colour = QColor(Qt.white) if self.hidden else self.display_colour
        painter.setRenderHint(QPainter.Antialiasing)
        painter.setPen(colour)
        painter.setBrush(QBrush(colour))
        # painter.drawEllipse(self.__x, self.__y, self.__width, self.__height)
        painter.drawEllipse(self.boundingRect())

    def get_coordinates(self):
        return (self.pos().x(), self.pos().y())

    def boundingRect(self):
        return QRectF(-0.5*self.__width,
                      -0.5*self.__height,
                      self.__height, self.__width)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = QGraphicsView()
    scene = QGraphicsScene(w)
    w.setScene(scene)
    it = EllipseObject(x=100, y=100, hidden=False)
    scene.addItem(it)

    animation = QPropertyAnimation(it, b"scale")
    animation.setDuration(2000)
    animation.setStartValue(2)
    animation.setEndValue(1)
    animation.start()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Note:

Instead of using flag called `hidden`, use `setVisible(boolean)`, `show()` or `hide()` directly. Qt already has many methods implemented, *the wheel does not reinvent*.

Comment: oh my god man, thank you, thank you so much, you saved my life! Thanks!!!